# How do I non-interactively update FreeBSD system (and ports)?

Tags: freebsd

Essentially, I am looking for a fully silent, non-interactive version of

```
freebsd-update fetch
freebsd-update install
```

and

```
portsnap fetch update
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For FreeBSD < 10, the following works:

Allow `freebsd-update` to run fetch without `stdin` attached to a terminal:

```
sed 's/\[ ! -t 0 \]/false/' /usr/sbin/freebsd-update > /tmp/freebsd-update
chmod +x /tmp/freebsd-update
```

Allow `portsnap` to run fetch without `stdin` attached to a terminal:

```
sed 's/\[ ! -t 0 \]/false/' /usr/sbin/portsnap > /tmp/portsnap
chmod +x /tmp/portsnap
```

Credits: [veewee](https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee/blob/master/templates/freebsd-9.1-RELEASE-amd64/postinstall.sh)

---

For FreeBSD 10+, the solution in the answer below by @uchida should be preferred!

Comment: Outstanding! I was looking for this to automate an installation!

Answer (score 9):

On FreeBSD-10.2 there's a new option to allow this:

`freebsd-update fetch --not-running-from-cron`

[From the manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=freebsd-update&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD+10.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html):

```
 --not-running-from-cron
        Force freebsd-update fetch to proceed when there is no
        controlling tty.  This is for use by automated scripts and
        orchestration tools.  Please do not run freebsd-update
        fetch from crontab or similar using this flag, see:
        freebsd-update cron
```

Comment: Ah, still giving the crazy MORE button.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @dentarg Except it doesn't work. As zsero says, the fetch operation will still require some interaction to complete.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde I see what you mean, but it is working as intended. As stated above, `freebsd-update(8)` says: "Force freebsd-update fetch to proceed when there is **no controlling tty**. This is for use by automated scripts and orchestration tools". Works great for me, when using Ansible, for example.

Comment: @dentarg It also helped me as well, it just doesn't fully answer the question as stated.

Comment: If you want to try this from the commandline, you can do it this way: `freebsd-update install --not-running-from-cron </dev/null`

Answer (score 8):

On FreeBSD 10.0R and later, set PAGER environment variable on freebsd-update

```
env PAGER=cat freebsd-update fetch
freebsd-update install
```

For [portsnap(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=portsnap&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html%20%22%22) on FreeBSD 10.0R and later, default behaviour, namely without `--interactive` option, is non-interactive.

```
portsnap fetch update
```

Comment: For FreeBSD 10+, this should be the preferred way, rather the monkey patching I describe above.

Comment: It's documented now: https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=r367678

Answer (score 3):

Blindly installing updates (even `freebsd-update` updates) can be a Bad Thing: One option in `rc.conf` changes, and suddenly your machine has no SSH daemon anymore.

Similarly you probably don't want to blindly install all available port updates via `portsnap` / `portupgrade -a` -- you might take a major version number bump and break the universe, or you might just have a port with new configuration options that *need* to be changed (you can make ports just accept whatever their defaults are, but sometimes that's not what you want).

---

The *best* way to do this is to use a configuration management tool like [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com) or [radmind](http://rsug.itd.umich.edu/software/radmind/) to deploy your changes.
Make a machine template based on a box you've successfully upgraded and tested, then deploy that to the rest of your environment. This ensures that you're pushing out a working system configuration, and that you only have to do the manual steps once (on the machine you're templating from).

Comment: Does `freebsd-update` overwrite configuration data like `rc.conf`? But even if so: we want to automatically (nightly) create VM images (OVA, AMI, ..) from scratch. Hence, there is no problem of configs overwritten, since after base install, the system is first updated, and then configured. So how do I run `freebsd-update` and `portsnap` unattended? On RH Linux, I just fire `yum -y update` and voila. How do I do that with FreeBSD?

Comment: `freebsd-update` generally doesn't overwrite configuration files, but it will replace stock `rc` scripts in `/etc/rc.d` when they're updated. (I believe it checks `rc.conf` and friends for obvious problems, but I could be wrong. I still build my systems the old fashioned way with `make world` & `mergemaster`).

Comment: the short answer to your question though is "You don't blindly install updates." -- it's irresponsible to do so (I can tell you horror stories of production environments destroyed by `yum -y update`). If the tool asks you a question it's because it really needs you to stop, think, and respond. You can always pipe `yes` to `freebsd-upgrade` and run `portupgrade --batch` if you want to, but IMHO that's a pretty big foot-gun.

Comment: already tried: `yes | freebsd-upgrade ...` does not work .. it bails out "you should not run non-interactive ..". However, I am updating a _fresh_ install. I fail to see any risk in doing that.

Comment: @oberstet that's only for fetch (and it tells you what to do about it *in the error message*). Also to be blunt I don't think you know the requirements of `freebsd-upgrade` better than the dude who wrote it (he's been doing this longer than ***I*** have, and he's pretty good at this whole "write stuff that doesn't destroy the universe" thing), but if you *really* think you know better it's just a shell script -- You can copy it and hack to your heart's content to make it behave how you want...

Comment: So you say `freebsd-update` (sorry, I meant _update_ not _upgrade_) could destroy a system _freshly_ installed from ISOs when answering "yes" to everything it asks? Rgd the fetch: I don't want to use cron, I want to fetch updates immediately (from Fabric/ssh). So I have to _hack_ `freebsd-upgrade`?

Comment: No it won't destroy a newly installed system. He's worrying you'll blow up your systems and obviously didn't read any of the bits about nightly images.

Answer (score -1):

For FreeBSD version > 11

freebsd-update is a script and there is "Function for asking the user if everything is ok".
The function is:

continuep ()

It is enough to comment all in this function but the line with

return 0

After that this function returns positive answer to "y/n" question.

Important! Remember, this is NOT recommended and do that only on your OWN risk!

```
# /tmp/freebsd-update -r 11.1-RELEASE upgrade ; while [ $? -eq 1 ] ; do sleep 3; /tmp/freebsd-update -r 11.1-RELEASE upgrade ; done
```